# C++Builder 11.3 build an application for WinPE 5.0

Tags: c++builder, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, winpe

I would like to create a simple VCL application for WinPE.

I have created an 32bit application with C++Builder 11.3. The application contains a VCL edit box and button, but it does not run. An error message is displayed:

> This application is not supported by the OS

Is it generally possible to create a simple VCL application (Form + Edit + Button) for WinPE using C++Builder 11.3? What do I have to consider or set in the project settings so that the application runs?

I have created an application with XE7, which runs on WinPE.

Comment: What version and architecture type of WinPE are you using?  You say you are compiling a 32bit VCL app, are you using a 32bit x86 version of WinPE?

Comment: Have you compared the project settings between the XE7 project and the 11.3 project for differences?

Comment: WinPE doesn't have WOW64 so if you use 64-bit WinPE you must build a 64-bit app

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I create a 64Bit version, this starts now. The application should be a simple GUI for our backup and restore scripts. The next problem is, unfortunately the OpenFileDlg does not start. But the simple components like FileList and DirList work.You can help yourself with that, but the system dialog would be nicer.